# Using Foreman with Sidekiq, Neo4j and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j, foreman, neo4j.rb

In a Rails project I'm currently using [neo4j](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j) instead of ActiveRecord. I added the [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) and [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to be able to start Sidekiq and Rails server at the same time. This is what I have in the Procfile:

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
web: rails server
```

When I enter "foreman start" I'm getting this error:

```
14:39:29 worker.1 | LockClient[8447] can't wait on resource RWLock[SCHEMA(0), hash=754245282] since => LockClient[8447] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[SCHEMA(0), hash=754245282] <-[:WAITING_FOR]- LockClient[8448] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[SCHEMA(0), hash=754245282]
14:39:29 worker.1 | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/neo4j-core-3.0.8/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:163:in `raise_error'
14:39:29 worker.1 | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/neo4j-core-3.0.8/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_session.rb:210:in `_query_or_fail'
14:39:29 worker.1 | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/neo4j-core-3.0.8/lib/neo4j/label.rb:42:in `create_constraint'
... further stack trace
```

If I don't use Foreman and instead start Sidekiq and Rails in separate tabs, it works just fine. Anyone else had any similar issues?

Comment: Are you by any chance using Neo4j transactions in your app?

Comment: Can you show which kinds of queries you are running? Looks like a deadlock warning.